# Can database create relating tables at the same time and mandatorily on query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, database-design

Developing tool: C#
Database : SQL Server Express

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYkAI.jpg)

For the first time, I designed customer entity like model A which had phonenumber field.

But I changed the database design as B for another requirement.

My modelling is B because Customer has necessarily one or more telphoneNumber.

If one 'customer' entity occurs, one or more 'telephoneNumber' entities have to occur 'at the same time' and 'mandatorily'

Model C and model D are same.

I wonder what differences of query between model B and model C when creating tables and records at physical level.

I wonder it is possible to express 'at the same time' and 'mandatorily' at query

Can the database restrict 'at the same time' and 'mandatorily' on query?

Comment: Why did you delete your original question about this?

Comment: Are you asking about database migrations?

Comment: Do an `INNER JOIN` that will say 'at the same time' and 'mandatorily'.

Comment: i posted wrong attached image, so i posted again

Comment: not only migrations but also creating records